# Category redirect in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

On my wordpress site I can get category page by two links: http://domain/base_category/dist_category and http://domain/dist_category

I want second one link to redirect to first one. How can I perform permanent redirect in wordpress for all such nested categories?

Comment: You need to update your Permalink Structures.

Comment: my permalinks is set up to /%category%/%postname%/

Comment: Try make it /%postname%/